# Unable to target different area in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core

When i am using the asp-route-area tag helper to target a different area. The URL does not target it.

I have put the below code in the VIew of my Index method of 1 area:

```
<a asp-route-area="Employee" asp-action="List" asp-controller="Home">Link3</a>
```

The link formed is not targetting the Employee area. The link formed is :

```
<a href="/home/list/?area=Employee">Link3</a>
```

It should be:

```
<a href="/Employee/home/list/>Link3</a>
```

My route is:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areas",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

//Default Route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I did not added the attribute `[Area("Employee")]` on my Home Controller of Employee area.

Adding that attribute solved my problem.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace URLRouting.Areas.Employee.Controllers
{
    [Area("Employee")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `asp-area="Employee"`.

`asp-route-*` tag helper is used to populate route parameters if they are defined on the target action e.g. `[Get("path/{id}")]` can be populated by `asp-route-id="1"`.

If no matching route parameter can be found it is added to the query string, hence `?area=Employee` is added to your URL because you don't have a matching route parameter named area.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> Once you've defined the folder hierarchy, you need to tell MVC that each controller is associated with an area. You do that by decorating the controller name with the [Area] attribute.

Further below, its says that in the route configuration you should use `areaRoute` instead of `areas`

In your case I think it should be:

```
<a asp-route-area="areas" asp-area="Employee" asp-action="List" asp-controller="Home">Link3</a>
```